# Laravel testing phpunit press NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to setup phpunit tests for a project with Laravel 5.1.40 (LTS), php 5.6.28, and phpunit 4.8.27. I'm sorry if this issue has been solved before, but I couldn't find anything.

```
public function testAdminLogin()
{
     $this->visit('/auth/login')
         ->type('email@address.com', 'email')
         ->type('1234567890', 'password')
         ->press('Login');
}
```

There seem to be an issue with `press('STRING')` with both `<button>` and `<input>` as submit buttons. Below is the error message I receive.

```
1) ExampleTest::testAdminLogin
A request to [http://localhost/auth/login] failed. Received status code [500].

C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:165
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:63
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:85
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:684
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\InteractsWithPages.php:671
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\tests\ExampleTest.php:52
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
```

However, when I change the `<button>` tag to an `<a>` tag, add an id to it, and replace the `press(STRING)` function with the `click(ID)` function, the test passes. I could change the `<button>` to an `<a>`, but that would only a temporary fix, and future cases might not allow the tag change.

Below is the HTML form with the `<button>` tag.

```
<form action="/auth/login" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ old('email') }}" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-login">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using `Auth::routes()` or defining login/register routes manually?

Comment: I'm using the 5.1 version of laravel where it is defined manually

Answer (score 0):

You said you define auth routes manually. In this case you should have POST route for sending login form:

```
Route::post('auth/login', ....
```

It works in `a href` because it sends GET request for which you have route. Form sends POST request by default.

Comment: That one is defined in the routes file. I'm suspecting there's something shady going on with either the redirects or a bug with the press function. Because the click function passes the test as I wrote in the question